# listview with button and call the previous step after clicking

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, android-fragments

I'm new to android development. I have 2 `ListView`s. when I click on one item on the first `ListView`, the new dataset will show in the second one. I have added a `Button` to the second `ListView` (`onItemClick`). Using an `Adapter`. So when I click on the `Button` (Read more) it will load a new `Activity`. So when I click on the `Back` `Button` i need to load the same data(listview2) in my previous step.

```
int images[] ={R.drawable.boc, R.drawable.commercial, R.drawable.nations, R.drawable.popls};

    adp = new ItemsAdapter(getActivity(), images);
    menu.setAdapter(adp);

    menu.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listViewText);
            /*ImageButton imgbtn = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.AddButton);
            ImageButton imgbtn2 = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.AddInfo);
            */


            switch (arg2) {
            case 0:
                ListAdapter adapter3 = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), boc) ;
                menu2.setAdapter(adapter3);


                break;
            case 1:
                // menu2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                // android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,subitems2));
                ListAdapter adapter4 = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), bankcrcards) ;
                menu2.setAdapter(adapter4);
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

        }
    });

    menu2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ImageView imgbtn1 = (ImageView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            imgbtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    expandableListView=new ExpandableListFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.setCustomAnimations( R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                    transaction.replace(R.id.myFragement,expandableListView);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    transaction.commit();
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I propose that instead of using two `ListView`s, you use an `ExpandableListView`. Two `ListView`s on the UI might not lead to a good experience.

There's [details here](http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_category/dealing-with-data) on how to deal with vast amounts of data.

An [example here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) should help you with implementation of an `ExpandableListView`

Answer (score 0):

Using 2 listviews in 1 activity is not recommended as it can cause you flows issues (Like the one you are facing right now).

Consider using only 1 listview, if there's different items override the following function (of BaseAdapter) to show correct views:

```
 @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return super.getViewTypeCount();
    }
```

This will solve the 2 listview issue, than, when clicking on item and opening new activity you can save the an instance state of the list view so when you press back you can use the following [example](http://blog.denevell.org/android-save-list-position-rotation-backpress.html) to see how to return to previous state.

Good luck